# Use feeder next 10 results and repeat the request 10 times in Gatling

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I am using Gatling 3.6.1 and I am trying to repeat the request 10 times for the next 10 products from the feeder file. This is what I tried:

```
feed(products, 10)
      .repeat(10, "index") {
        exec(session => {
          val index = session("index").as[Int]
          val counter = index + 1
          session.set("counter", counter)
        })
        .exec(productIdsRequest())
      }

  private def productIdsRequest() = {
      http("ProductId${counter}")
        .get(path + "products/${product_code${counter}}")
        .check(jsonPath("$..code").count.gt(2))
  }
```

I am having trouble getting the counter value to my API URL.
I would like to have something like

```
products/${product_code1}, 
products/${product_code2} etc.
```

But instead, I get the error `'nested attribute definition is not allowed'`
So basically I would like that every request gets called with one product from the feeder (in the batch of 10 products)
Can you please help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't know how realized your feeder `products`.

If I clearly understand you - just need to move `.repeat` on high level:

```
.repeat(10, "counter") {
      feed(product)
        .exec(http("ProductId ${counter}")
          .get("products/${product_code}")
          .check(jsonPath("$..code").count.gt(2)))
    }
```